# Writing system of equations & rate of change

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

"Two planes leave a city for another city that us 600 miles away. One of the planes is flying 50 miles per hour faster than the other. The slower plane takes 2 hours longer to reach the city. What is the rate of each plane? Write and solve a system of equations."

I am aware that d=rt, where d represents distance, r represents rate, and t represents time. I also know how to solve systems of equations. I am unsure on how to create the system of equations from the information given. I would like some hints as to how to start/she would like some help getting on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: Hints?  Translate what you know (d=rt, problem statement, ... ) into the requested equations. It appears d=600 miles for both planes. The rate differs by 50 mph. You should write this as r1 and r2 as this is what you are looking for. But, it's also true that you have r1 and r2=r1+50. Try the same thing with the two times. Be careful about whether you are saying plane 1 is faster or slower than plane 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the rate and time of the first plane $r_{1}$ and $t_{1}$, respectively. Since we know the journey is 600 miles, we have $600 = r_{1}t_{1}$. Now, let us look at the second plane. We know that the second plane takes 2 hours longer, and it is going 50 mph slower, and it also travels 600 miles, so the two equations we have are:

$600 = r_{1}t_{1}$ and $600 = (r_{1}-50)(t_{1} + 2)$

Answer (score 1):

From your starting point of $d = rt$, we set up an equation for each plane.

Plane 1:
It reaches a city that is 600 miles away in T amount of time. It is flying at a speed S.

So its equation is $600 = TS$.

Plane 2:
It reaches that same city 2 hours later or T + 2 hours. It is traveling 50 miles slower than Plane 1 or S - 50.

Then it's equation is $600 = (T+2)(S-50)$

Hope that helps.

Comment: Surely you don't think that the slower plane is the one to arrive faster.

Comment: Woops! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Quick question: how do we know plane 2 is the slower plane, but also travels 50mph faster?